# Illustrator gradient tool won't change direction

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

In Illustrator CS6, I can only get the gradient tool to add a horizontal gradient.

I can not drag either of the end points around into a vertical gradient.

What is going on here that I can't see?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With linear gradients, you can not drag the gradient annotator around to various angles. It will remain at the angle it has been set to.

If you want to drag an angle, use the Gradient Tool and click where you want the gradient to start then drag to where you want the gradient to end. You can click-drag any angle you need.

Alternatively, you can use the Angle field located on the Gradient Panel to set the angle of the gradient.

It is only with radial gradients that the annotator will rotate around it's center, never with linear gradients.

Comment: Thanks, I've been using Fireworks for 8 years; old habits die hard!

Answer (score 4):

Had the same exact problem.  Make sure that your fill is selected and not the stroke.  This was my issue.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

There is a slider in the panel for the angle of the gradient. You can also enter a numeric value there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. What's happening is since in cs6 you can also gradient the stroke now, you have to toggle over to the fill so that the gradient tool will respond. For example, I was trying to make a black bar fade to 0% opacity. So I made my bar black and NO STROKE. Then selected my gradient tool and even used the gradient palette and nothing would resound. Finally, I realized I was trying to manipulate my non-existent stroke, once I toggled to the fill, it responded like normal.

Answer (score -1):

How to unlock gradient tool in adobe illustrator?

here it is : 
Press X in your keyboard if your gradient tool is showing blocked sign.

[image]

Comment: Please do not use our community to promote your business. If you have a blog with information that is relevant to the question you're answering then you're welcome to include it IN ADDITION TO the answer.